# How do I change a div from popup to slide down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not very good with javascript and I have this javascript code. When I click on the link the div shows and hides. The problem is the showing effect, it pops up and doesn't look good so I want the div to slide down when it shows.
Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var s;
ShowHideWidget = {

    settings : {
       clickHere : document.getElementById('clickHere'),
       dropdown_signup : document.getElementById('dropdown_signup')
    },

    init : function() {
        //kick things off
        s = this.settings;
        this.bindUIActions();
    },

    bindUIActions : function() {
        //Attach handler to the onclick
        /*
        s.clickHere.onclick = function() {
            ShowHideWidget.toggleVisibility(s.showing);
            return false;
        };
        */
        ShowHideWidget.addEvent(s.clickHere, 'click', function() {    
            ShowHideWidget.toggleVisibility(s.dropdown_signup);
        });
    },

    addEvent : function(element, evnt, funct) {
        //addEventListener is not supported in <= IE8
        if (element.attachEvent) {
            return element.attachEvent('on'+evnt, funct);
        } else {
          return element.addEventListener(evnt, funct, false);
        }
    },

    toggleVisibility : function(id) {
        if(id.style.display == 'block') {
          id.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
          id.style.display = 'block';
       };
    }

};

(function() {
    ShowHideWidget.init();
})();
</script>
```

Comment: can you post in jsfiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/66aKc/ 

@CodingAnt

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/66aKc/29/ Are you happy with such an answer? 

But it require jQuery to work :) 

    $(id).animate({
     left: "+=50",
     height: "toggle"
    }, 500, function() {
    });

Comment: yaa ... pretty cool , that's what iam talking about :D

Comment: can i ask you if i want the user if he clicked on a blank space to close the dropdoown ???
like he doesn't need to click the button again ..??

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using jquery `slideDown` and `slideUp` functions:

Add following code:

```
toggleVisibility : function(id) {
    if( $(id).is(':visible') ){
       $(id).slideUp();
    } else {
       $(id).slideDown();
    }  
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kY3XX/)

Answer (score 0):

You'd do well to use something like jQuery's [.slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) function. You'll have to write a lot of code to do this yourself.